# insert char in string using batch script

Tags: batch-file

From batch script i'm getting values from registry:
32000000800A00004C00000000180000ED00000000180000. there are which contains 3 values each one is of 16 characters. How can I get 3 separate values? I've tried using for loop but as far as I understand delimiter & tokens are required. I've tried to add '-' after every 16th char but failed. Can any one please help me here?
expected o/p: 32000000800A0000-4C00000000180000-ED00000000180000.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52293497/edit) to include the code you are using to retrieve the registry data, and properly explain your task relative to that code.

Comment: BTW your example contains **three** 16 characters values. You repeated _"2 values"_ two times...

Comment: *modified. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "value=32000000800A00004C00000000180000ED00000000180000"

call :binary "%value%"
if defined newvalue set "newvalue=%newvalue:~0,-1%"

echo "%newvalue%"
exit /b

:binary
set "chunk=%~1"
set "newvalue=%newvalue%%chunk:~,16%-"
set "value=%value:~16%"
if defined value call :binary "%value%"
```

This gets every 16 characters and appends a `-` as a delimiter.

The label `:binary` is called. The variable named `chunk`
gets the value of the 1st argument. `newvalue` gets the value
the next 16 characters and appends the `-`. The `value` is trimmed
of the 16 characters at start and if still defined, the `:binary`
label is called again to do the next 16 characters.

Once done, trim off trailing `-` and then expect
result `32000000800A0000-4C00000000180000-ED00000000180000`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something in the following form:

(smaller example to save my typing 123456789 -> 123-456-789)

```
set xx=123456789
echo %xx:~0,3%-%xx:~3,3%-%xx:~6,3%
```

or maybe ...

```
set xx=32000000800A00004C00000000180000ED00000000180000
echo %xx:~0,16%-%xx:~16,16%-%xx:~32,16%
```

Comment: how can I do this dynamically? i.e. delimited by group of 3 chr. (as mentioned in your example) instead of hard coded string splitting.

Comment: @akashmendapara Dynamically as in what? Does your string split requirements change? How do you plan on determining that?.. Maybe if you post how the get the values in the batch file currently, by actually posting your batch code, we could determine what you're trying to do.

Comment: actually no of registry values are continuously increasing. as of now there are total 3 values each contains 16 char. currently i'm storing all reg values in single variable. I want to divide in group of 16 char as mentioned in expected o/p.

Comment: maybe share the relevant parts of your script and say what it is not doing correctly ?

Comment: I was trying using for loop but not working. I am not much aware about batch scripting. It will be great if any one can suggest required changes`set s=32000000800A00004C00000000180000ED0000000018000;`
`set b=0;`
`:loop`
`echo %a%`
`for /F %%b in (%s%) do echo (%s:~b,16%)`
`echo %%b` 
`set /a "b=b+16"`
`goto :loop`